# How can I make chrome being controlled by Selenium load the Chropath extension by default?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests

I want to be able to use extensions (mainly chropath) while testing using selenium web driver.  How can I set up my script to load extensions by default?  It currently opens a page with no extensions enabled and does not remember if I enable extensions during a session.

Thank yoU!

Comment: Is there any specific extensions you're looking for ?

Comment: Chropath https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code in Python.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import. 
 DesiredCapabilities'

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/pathtoChromeextension.crx")); 

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

You can use this to get crx file http://crxextractor.com/ from your extension id.

Comment: I think this might work but I have to figure out how to do it in python.  This looks like java code.